# Display toast notification without button click using LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, community, toast

Here is the logic which is working fine while using the button, but I'm trying to display the notification once the page is loaded.
this logic which I tried,
js:

```
import { LightningElement,wire,track } from 'lwc';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import toastMsg from '@salesforce/apex/ToastCtrl.toastMessage';
export default class toastcmp extends LightningElement {
    @wire(toastMsg)
    toast;
    notification(){
        const evt = new ShowToastEvent({
            title: 'Message',
            message:this.toast.data.Message__c,
            variant: 'info'
        });
        this.dispatchEvent(evt);
    }
}
```

html:

```
<template>
   <lightning-button label="Click" onclick={notification}></lightning-button>
</template>
```

Can anyone provide the solution? I tried using this but it is showing an empty page, it is not working.
connectedCallback(){
this.notification();
}
Thanks, in advance.

Comment: What is meant by "but it is showing an empty page"? `connectedCallback(){ this.notification(); }` works fine on a `lightning__RecordPage`.

Comment: TSmith is correct - you have to call `this.notification()` inside the `connectedCallback()` for the toast to fire on component load.  `connectedCallback()` is a standard function for LWCs that'll run on load. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.create_lifecycle_hooks_dom

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
import {LightningElement, wire} from "lwc";
import {ShowToastEvent} from "lightning/platformShowToastEvent";
import toastMsg from "@salesforce/apex/ToastCtrl.toastMessage";
export default class toastcmp extends LightningElement {
    @wire(toastMsg)
    toast;

    notification() {
        const evt = new ShowToastEvent({
            title: "Message",
            message: this.toast.data.Message__c,
            variant: "info"
        });
        this.dispatchEvent(evt);
    }

    connectedCallback() {
        this.notification();
    }
}
```

html:

```
<template>
</template>
```